# MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL fails when MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink succeeds

Tags: ms-media-foundation

There are two ways to create a `IMFSinkWriter`:

### With `MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink`

```cpp
winrt::com_ptr<IMFByteStream> outputStream;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_READWRITE, MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, L"D:\\Documents\\test.mp4", outputStream.put()));
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaSink> mp4StreamSink;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink(outputStream.get(), m_videoOut.get(), NULL, mp4StreamSink.put()));
winrt::com_ptr<IMFSinkWriter> sinkWriter;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mp4StreamSink.get(), m_containter_attributes.get(), sinkWriter.put()));
sinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(0, m_videoIn.get(), nullptr);
```

### With `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL`

```cpp
winrt::com_ptr<IMFSinkWriter> pSinkWriterVideo;
winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(L"D:\\Documents\\test2.mp4", NULL, m_containter_attributes.get(), pSinkWriterVideo.put()));
winrt::check_hresult(pSinkWriterVideo->AddStream(m_videoOut.get(), &m_videoStreamIndex));
// BOOM! when size is irregular
winrt::check_hresult(pSinkWriterVideo->SetInputMediaType(m_videoStreamIndex, m_videoIn.get(), nullptr /*encoder attributes*/));
```

If `MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE` is set to `{1920, 1080}` both succeed. But if set to `{1922, 1089}` then just the `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL` alternative fails. To be clear it fails at `IMFSinkWriter::SetInputMediaType`.

Repro: https://github.com/tom-huntington/ConsoleApplication13MediaStreamSource

Comment: In your code (not shown here) you force the *input* media type with MFVideoFormat_ARGB32 and MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, means the video is uncompressed while it's not.

Comment: @SimonMourier "the video is uncompressed while it's not". I don't understand. The input media type (`IMFSinkWriter::SetInputMediaType`) was intended be uncompressed. Only the output media type `IMFSinkWriter::AddStream` is compressed. Maybe I have to set the encoder explicitly.

Comment: Of course, sorry, I got all mixed up...

Comment: It's probably about 1089 being odd. Note that U, V components of H.264 are normally subsampled 4:2:0 and hence odd heights might be a problem. It's not even about possibility of H.264 be of odd height, such media types might be considered invalid by partts of the pipeline as a part of safety check or at conversion step.

Comment: 1088 works fine, so it seems like being odd is the problem. It seems like the encoder is configured differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample` fails when writing with an odd height.

- So it seems that there is a bug in the validation for `MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink`/`MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink`.
- And that `MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL` is doing the correct thing.
- And also that Roman's comment is correct:

> It's probably about 1089 being odd. Note that U, V components of H.264 are normally subsampled 4:2:0 and hence odd heights might be a problem.